# update conditionally a field in case parameter is not null

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I need a query to update one field. If the passed parameter is null the do NOT update it with the null value of the parameter

```
update myTable 
set myField1 = :param1
```

environment: hibernate and oracle

Answer (score 5):

Can't you just put it in there where clause?

```
update myTable
   set myField1 = :param1
 where :param1 is not null
```

That'll avoid extra DML. Alternatively you can do:

```
update myTable
   set myField1 = decode(:param1, null, myField1, :param)
```

But that means you'll update a field to the same, which isn't really optimal when you don't have to.

Comment: @geo - I recommend the first version.  Except that :param1 and :param should be the same parameter...

Comment: @Dems, well caught! I've updated it. I'd assumied by geo's choice that there are more columns being updated, which would mean that the second query was correct...